# Store an image name and extension in DB?

Tags: database, image-manipulation

If a user uploads an avatar and I create:

```
1. example.png
2. example_large.png
3. example_small.png
```

(note: jpg and png are allowed)

Is it best to store the raw image name ('example' in this case) and the image extension in two separate columns?

**EDIT**

for example:

```
    image_name | image_ext
    -----------------------
    example    | .png
```

**END EDIT**

Or maybe use a regex to remove the extension and then add it back (with the desired size: large, thumb, etc)?

Or maybe I'm insane and should just change my naming convention...

Comment: Did someone just vote to close this? If this is a duplicate I'm sorry - I searched the site up and down and couldn't find a similar question

Comment: Where are the images stored? On the file system? Does your code ever care what the image type is? Do you do any image processing? What is your main concern here? Storage efficiency?

Comment: the image is uploaded via user, stored on the server, and then (at least I though was good practice) resized into three different images for speed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose if you wanted to query on the extension i.e. give me all the 'large' images then there would be value in storing the extension in a separate column.  If you have no reason to query, sort, report etc on the extension that just keep it in one.

In short if the extension itself is significant than an argument can be made for storing it separately.

**EDIT**

Even with your edit the answer is the same if the extension is a significant piece of data i.e. you want to query on all "png" then store them separately if its not then just store them together.

Comment: I don't understand, how else would I get the image if I didn't know the extension?

Comment: Maybe I don't understand your question I thought you were asking do you store example_large.png in one column or example in one and large in another.

Comment: no no ... I'll update my question - sorry I must not have been clear

Comment: ok.. but how do I get the example_large.png images? (sorry if this is really noobish)

Comment: Either store example_large in one column and .png in another or example_large.png in one column.  If all pieces are particularly important than store them all in their own columns, example large .png I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish here.

Comment: I think you have answered my question. I figured that if I knew there was a 'large' and 'thumb' version I just wouldn't put those in the DB and just call the names when I needed them. Oh well... thanks for the help

Comment: That would work as well, any combination works its a question of what problem are you trying to solve.